# How to convert -v flag to Dockerfile VOLUME argument

Tags: docker, docker-volume, large-data-volumes

I'm attempting to create a MongoDB Docker container using a data directory on my host machine. This works just fine if I run `docker` from the command line:

```sh
docker run \
    --detach \
    --name db_backup \
    --publish 27017:27017 \
    --volume $PWD/data:/backup/db \
    mongo:latest \
    mongod --dbpath /backup/db
```

I'm having a couple of problems converting the above command to a Dockerfile, particularly the `--volume` argument:

1. The backup directory can be quite big—upwards of 50GB—and it take a long time to build the image.
2. When I use the `VOLUME` argument in the `Dockerfile` I'm not clear on how to put it in the right place so that I can reference it with the `--dbpath` flag when executing `mongod`.

Here's what my Dockerfile looks like at the moment.

```
FROM mongo:latest

VOLUME ./data

EXPOSE 27017 27017

CMD [ "mongod", "--dbpath", "/backup/db" ]
```

I should mention that I've added ./data to my `.dockerignore` (not sure if thats ok) otherwise it take too long to build the image. This seems to work fine when using the `--volume` flag.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything; a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive isn't necessary here, and you can't use it to specify a specific host directory.  Even if you build a custom image you will need to run something very similar to your original `docker run` command, including its `--publish` and `--volume` options.

Comment: @DavidMaze so are the `--volume` flag and `VOLUME` argument unrelated? What is the difference?

Comment: `VOLUME` is an instruction to Docker to create and mount a new empty anonymous volume on the named directory if nothing else is mounted there.  It comes with some confusing side effects, like preventing future `RUN` instructions from changing that directory.  You can't control the name or physical location of the volume, and you can use `docker run -v` on any directory whether or not its declared as a `VOLUME`.  You almost never need `VOLUME`.